# Taking an Introductory Analysis Course Without Prior Proof Writing Experience

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, education

I am planning on taking an intro to real analysis course offered by my university to increase my graduate school admission chances. I do have a solid understanding of differentiation and pretty good knowledge of integration. However, I have zero proof writing experience. The book being used is *A First Course in Real Analysis* by Protter and Morrey and the course description is as follows:

**Topics include finite and infinite sets, axiomatic study of real numbers, topology of Cartesian spaces, sequences of functions, continuous functions, differentiation of functions of one variable.**

A prerequisite for the course is discrete math which I have not taken yet so this is primarily why I am concerned. And I don't have the time to take discrete math first as I am sending my graduate applications out in a few months.

Will I be totally lost or is it practically possible to power through it with at least a B?

Thank you all for the input in advance!

Comment: It is folly to apply to graduate school without several years of experience writing proofs. Get a book like *How to Think like a Mathematician* by Houston and work through it carefully and in a thorough manner. You should do a proof-based linear algebra course and an abstract algebra course before doing analysis. (I say this with 40 years' experience teaching and advising math majors.)

Comment: I think you should try and read a bit of the textbook to gauge how you feel about the material. Books like *How to Prove It* will help learn proof techniques so you could start there.

Comment: Hi Ted, I'm not a math major; I plan on taking this course for graduate study in economics. But thanks for the input.

Comment: @TedShifrin For what it is worth, students at my university typically do the abstract algebra and real analysis classes concurrently. A rigorous linear algebra course does usually come first though.

Comment: Oh, your question was certainly unclear. Yes, lots of economics grad schools require this course, but you still need serious proof experience before taking it.

Comment: In general, mathematics courses list prerequisites for good reason. The subject is unavoidably cumulative.

Comment: Why are you asking us, instead of asking someone on the math faculty at your institution – if possible, someone who knows you, or someone with a title like "undergraduate advisor"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Discrete Math course is your school's introduction to proof writing, so skipping it might be a handicap.  However, last Summer I tutored a student in just your situation.  He needed Real Analysis to get into a graduate economics course.  He was bright and worked really hard.  We did two 2-hour sessions each week.  The proofs were very difficult for him but he mostly managed.

Was he successful?  He got a B+.  He needed an A for his program so he didn't get in.

So it's possible that you could take the course and get a decent grade.  Will it be decent enough? is another question.